# Query works in SQLDeveloper but not in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INGRESO_SALIDA_BUQUES WHERE ID_BUQUE = 1;
```

which works when I execute it in SQLDeveloper. It returns one row and just one column: the biggest ID where ID_BUQUE = 1.

Now, I'm using jdbc to connect to the database and do the same operation. Here is the code:

```
String sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAXIMO FROM INGRESO_SALIDA_BUQUES ";
    sql += "WHERE ID_BUQUE = " + registroSalida.getIdBuque();

PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    recursos.add(prepStmt);
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

The las line of code is the one that throws the error.

The result from the eclipse console (For your reference "Nombre de columna no válido" means invalid column name):

```
18:40:27,712 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) SQLException:Nombre de columna no válido
18:40:27,712 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.sql.SQLException: Nombre de columna no válido
18:40:27,713 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3724)
18:40:27,713 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2799)
18:40:27,713 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
```

I tried deleting all rows except 1, in order to see hat would happen if **I change MAX(ID) TO ID**. This query works. I tried again MAX(ID) with just one row and it failed again.

The table has was created with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE INGRESO_SALIDA_BUQUES (
    ID NUMBER,
    ID_BUQUE NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FECHA_INGRESO DATE NOT NULL,
    FECHA_SALIDA DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ISB PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ISB_ID_BUQUE FOREIGN KEY (ID_BUQUE) REFERENCES BUQUE(ID));
```

Do you know how to solve this?

recursos is just just an ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Object> recursos;
```

And in the constructor I initialize it. 
    recursos = new ArrayList();

I use it to save the resources necesary to the SQL statement, in order to close them later.

The method to close them is this:

```
public void cerrarRecursos() {
    for(Object ob : recursos){
        if(ob instanceof PreparedStatement)
            try {
                ((PreparedStatement) ob).close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line in your code throws the error?  What is `recursos` (the definition isn't included here)?  This probably isn't the source of your error but you really ought to use bind variables in your query and using `id` as the name of the key in each table generally isn't a good idea.

Comment: @JustinCave I edited the question. Regarding the use of bind variables, I will learn and use them, they seem very useful, thanks. Right know, I need this thing to work. I'll change the name of the key later.

Comment: Most likely `registroSalida.getIdBuque()` returns a alpha value, such as 'blah'. Then your query gets converted to `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM INGRESO_SALIDA_BUQUES WHERE ID_BUQUE = blah;` and the DB engine thinks that you are comparing `ID_BUQUE` with another column `blah` in your table

Comment: @cha No, it's not that, it returns an Int.

Comment: @JustinCave I just tried changing the names, in order to avoid issues; no effect. Do you have any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: Print out the SQL statement that you assemble before you call `prepareStatement`.  I'd tend to guess along with @cha that your `registroSalida.getIdBuque()` call isn't returning the value you think it is.

Comment: From the stack trace the `invalid column name` error is coming from a `getString()` call, not the `execute()`. So it isn't in the code you've shown. When you process the result set are you looking for the column by name - since a variation works, are you doing `getString("ID")`? If so you either need to do `getString("MAXIMO")`, or change the alias in your query from MAXIMO to ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace shows the error is coming from

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
```

... so it's being raised from an `rs.getString()` call, not the `prepStmt.executeQuery()` you think it's coming from.

Since you said it works if you change you query to get `ID` instead of `MAX(ID)`, code you haven't shown is doing `rs.getString("ID")` - otherwise it would still have failed after that change. If you use a column name in the `getString` then it has to match the column alias from the query.

You can either change your result set handling to do `rs.getString("MAXIMO")` to use the alias you've shown in your query, or `rs.getString(1)` to use positional notation; or change the query alias from `MAXIMO` to `ID`.